# Replace self hosted agents with virtual machine scale agents?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-vm-scale-set

I have some troubles in understanding the capabilities of the [Azure virtual machine scale set agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops).

Let's assume I have *X* vm's for which at the moment I have *X* corresponding Self hosted agents configured.
I use those self hosted agents in order to execute some PowerShell scripts on the vm's.

Now, I want to understand, if there is a way in which I could replace those Self hosted agents by Azure virtual machine scale set agents.

Basically, if from the virtual scale agents, I could connect to those vm's and execute the before mentioned PowerShell scripts.

I can't really find anything on this topic, is it because that's why the self hosted exists?
Anyone have any experience on something similar?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi user2271933; it depends on what those powershell scripts are doing. Are your VMs a fixed part of your infrastructure, where you deploy and test your software, something like that? Is that what the powershell scripts are doing?

Comment: Hi @VinceBowdren. Yes - the VM's are a fixed part of the infrastructure. Also, yes to second part as well - those are some deploy activities performed by the PowerShell scripts (download, moving folders around, etc)

Comment: If the VM's are fixed (not being build by the pipeline), then why do you need a scaleset agent for this? Just install an Azure DevOps environment agent directly on the VM's.

Comment: @ErikP.Ernst you should post that as an Answer; I'd vote for it